# Enzyme Internal Error: configured enzyme adapter did not inherit from the EnzymeAdapter base class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I get the following error when using enzyme 3 in my project (previously used enzyme 2 and everything worked):

```
Enzyme Internal Error: configured enzyme adapter did not inherit from the EnzymeAdapter base class


  at validateAdapter (node_modules/enzyme/build/validateAdapter.js:17:11)
  at Object.merge [as configure] (node_modules/enzyme/build/configuration.js:24:42)
  at Object.<anonymous> (test/enzyme-setup.js:4:8)
```

`enzyme-setup.js` is the following file:

```
const Enzyme = require('enzyme');
const Adapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-15');

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my case was that I used `npm link` to another package which uses enzyme too. When the other project imported enzyme he got it's own instance of enzyme which wasn't configured, resulting this error.

I solved this by passing enzyme to the other package so it would used my package enzyme instead of importing its own.